# Masquerading as another user from sudoers file?

Tags: sudo

My `/etc/sudoers` file has following entries:-

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
agupta ALL= /sbin/,/usr/sbin/,/bin/,/bin/cat /etc/sudoers
ADMINS ALL= !/usr/bin/su, !SHELLS
alice ALL =(%Children) /sbin/, /usr/sbin/, /bin/
```

alice is a member of the Children group; please find below are details for alice:-

```
[alice@localhost ~]$ id alice
uid=1005(alice) gid=1004(Children) groups=1004(Children)
```

When I try to run this command `/bin/cat /etc/sudoers` i get following errors:-

```
[alice@localhost ~]$ sudo  cat /etc/sudoers
Sorry, user alice is not allowed to execute '/bin/cat /etc/sudoers' as root on localhost.localdomain.
```

In /var/log/secure, I can see the following entries being populated:-

```
Mar 21 06:40:40 localhost sudo:    alice : command not allowed ; TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/alice ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/cat /etc/sudoers
```

Any suggestions on this?

---

**Edit 1**

Modified the file by removing the impersonation from the file i.e.

```
alice ALL = /sbin/, /usr/sbin/, /bin/
```

I was able to run the command `sudo cat /etc/sudoers` . I want to try out masquerading: but I am not able to make it work on my system

---

**Edit 2**

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
agupta,myself    ALL=(wheel)  ALL
jane ALL=(%parents) ALL
```

Command I ran:-

```
[jane@localhost ~]$ sudo -u paul cat /etc/sudoers
[sudo] password for jane:
cat: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
```

Logs in /etc/log/secure:-

```
Mar 15 15:26:24 localhost sudo:     jane : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/jane ; USER=paul ; COMMAND=/bin/cat /etc/sudoers
```

Members of the group parents:-

```
[root@localhost ~]# id jane
uid=505(jane) gid=504(parents) groups=504(parents)
[root@localhost ~]# id paul
uid=504(paul) gid=504(parents) groups=504(parents)
```

Am, I still making any silly mistake?

Comment: I don't know the sudoers syntax in detail, but I think you'll normally want to specify *either* a user name or a group, instead of both.

Comment: What do you mean by masquerading? What are you trying to do?

Comment: by masquerading, I mean to run a command as another user/group.

Comment: @gilles; I am trying to run a command as a different user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The to use the impersonating features of sudo (it defaults to user root) you need to use the -u option like this:

```
sudo -u agupta ls ~agupta
```

In addition, if agupta is in the Children group, to do that you need to run sudo under sudo:

```
sudo -u agupta sudo cat /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: i am not able to use masquerading feature at all. Should both the users belong to the same group?

Comment: Masquerading is done using the -u switch in sudo, the user doing the masquerading should have permissions to run the command in question as the user you want it to masquerade. In your case alice should be able to run the binaries in /sbin /usr/bin and /bin as any member of the Children group, but the member of the children group must be mentioned with the -u switch.

Comment: +1, thanks for the explanation David. I am using "u" switch with sudo to run the command but I am getting permission denied error. I have edited my question to include the changes.

Comment: :o, I forgot to use second sudo and to add other user from the same group to visudo. Making the necessary changes solved the problem. So here are the log entries in /var/log/secure:- `Mar 15 15:42:33 localhost sudo:     jane : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/jane ; USER=paul ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/sudo cat /etc/sudoers
Mar 15 15:42:33 localhost sudo:     paul : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/jane ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/cat /etc/sudoers
`